# Using a string for entertext.insert()

Tags: python, string, insert

I have been trying to get something to happen for each character in a string. This currently works, but instead I want to change the entertext by 1 each time it loops. However, I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't find any way to fix it, thanks.

```
    num = str(0)
    for char in string.ascii_uppercase:
        charPerc=round(100*float(var1[char])/float(totalCount),3)
        strChar = str(charPerc)
        test = 'entertext' + num
        test.insert(END, char +' = ' + strChar + '%') 
        z+1
```

I need it to change because I would like the variable charPerc, which gives the percentage of the character in the total string, to change to the next entry box for each character.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't seem to make this clear, I am not trying to insert into a string but trying to insert into an entry text box. I am simply trying to change the name of the entertext box each time, rather than edit a string.

Comment: I believe string in python is immutable object

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the `str` object has no attribute `insert`.The `insert` attribute is for mutable objects like list but since strings are immutable you can not use it for them.

If you want to insert a sub-string at the end of your string you can simply use `+` operand.

```
test+=char +' = ' + strChar + '%'
```

And if you want to insert a string inside your string you can use slicing. :

example:

```
>>> s='example'
>>> index=3
>>> s[:3]+'***'+s[3:]
'exa***mple'
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the index you want to insert item, then create new string

```
index = 2 
newString = oldString[:index] + item+oldString[index:]
```